# Show alert and fade it out every time it is shown in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function in a Javascript file that shows an alert every time I click on a button that checks an input field:

```
function createAlert(message){
   var alert = document.createElement("div");
   alert.setAttribute("class","alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show");
   alert.setAttribute("role","alert");
   alert.innerHTML = message;
   document.getElementById("modalBody").appendChild(alert);
}
```

Then I have this code that fades out the alert when it is shown:

```
$(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
            $(this).remove(); 
        });
    }, 8000);
});
```

I want that this function works every time the alert fades in, but it works only the first time and then not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you create the message set already everything on it. In that case, it will always be applied per alert message, so if multiple will popup, all wait 8 seconds (individually) and then fade out. Here's an example:

```js
function createAlert(message){
  var alert = document.createElement("div");
  alert.setAttribute("class","alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show");
  alert.setAttribute("role","alert");
  alert.innerHTML = message;
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(alert).fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
      $(this).remove(); 
    });
  }, 8000);
  document.getElementById("modalBody").appendChild(alert);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" onclick="createAlert('HAHAHA');" value="Create message" />
  <div id="modalBody"></div>
</body>
</html>
```